# Ext JS: FormPanel not populating fields with JSON data

Tags: extjs

I have a FormPanel with 3 fields and a JsonReader. Here's the setup:

```
  var goalPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            idProperty: 'id',          
            root: 'items',             
            fields: [
                {name: 'referenceSales', type:'float'},
                {name: 'increasePercentage', type: 'float'},
                {name: 'salesGoal', type: 'float'}
            ]
        }), 
        labelAlign: 'top',
        frame:true,
        bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
        items: [{
            layout:'column',
            items:[{
                columnWidth:.33,
                layout: 'form',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Reference Sales',
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    name: 'referenceSales',
                    readOnly: true,
                    disabled: true,
                    anchor:'95%'
                }]
            },{
                columnWidth:.33,
                layout: 'form',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Increase %',
                    name: 'increasePercentage',
                    xtype: 'numberfield',
                    anchor:'95%',
                    decimalPrecision: 2,

                    }
            }]},{
                columnWidth:.34,
                layout: 'form',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Sales Goal',
                    name: 'salesGoal',
                    xtype: 'numberfield',                   
                    anchor:'95%',
                    decimalPrecision: '2',

                }]
            }]
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Recalculate'
        }]
    });
```

Here's how I load the data:

```
goalPanel.getForm().load({url:'goal/getAnnualSalesGoal', method:'GET',params:myParams} );
```

Here's the JSON response, as seen in Firebug:

```
{"items":[{"referenceSales":700000,"salesGoal":749000,"increasePercentage":0.07}]}
```

I get no errors, and after load the form fields are definitely empty. How can I fix this, or begin to debug it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the docs for Ext.form.BasicForm, it says that JSON support is built in to BasicForm, so you don't need to use a JsonReader to load data into your form.  That shouldn't hurt though.

I think the main problem may be that load calls to BasicForm expect a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "referenceSales": 700000,
        "salesGoal": 749000,
        "increasePercentage": 0.07
    }
}
```

but yours is in an array.

(from the [Ext.form.BasicForm.load docs](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/output/Ext.form.Action.Load.html))

As a side note, if you're using Ext 3.0, `hbox` layout is much easier to deal with than `columns`.

Comment: I've modified the JSON response to look exactly like the above and removed the JsonReader, but the fields are still not populating...

Comment: How are you calling the load?  Something like `goalPanel.getForm().load({url: '/your/script.plx'});` ?

Comment: I had the same problem, the FormPanel required the 'data' property in the response be an array with one item in it just like in the question, otherwise it just didn't do anything. Adding the 'success':true was what fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its all there, you can't see it because the form height is 0.
Just set it like this:

```
var goalPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
    height:100,
    ...
```

Also there is a typo . This works for me:

```
        Ext.onReady(function() {
            var goalPanel = new Ext.FormPanel({
                reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    idProperty: 'id',          
                    root: 'items',             
                    fields: [
                        {name: 'referenceSales', type:'float'},
                        {name: 'increasePercentage', type: 'float'},
                                {name: 'salesGoal', type: 'float'}
                    ]
                }),     
                labelAlign: 'top',
                frame:true,
                bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
                height:100,
                items: [{
                        layout:'column',
                        items:[{
                                columnWidth:.33,
                                layout: 'form',
                                items: [{
                                        fieldLabel: 'Reference Sales',
                                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                                        name: 'referenceSales',
                                        readOnly: true,
                                        disabled: true,
                                        anchor:'95%'
                                }]
                        },{
                                columnWidth:.33,
                                layout: 'form',
                                items: [{
                                        fieldLabel: 'Increase %',
                                        name: 'increasePercentage',
                                        xtype: 'numberfield',
                                        anchor:'95%',
                                        decimalPrecision: 2,

                                        }
                        ]},{
                                columnWidth:.34,
                                layout: 'form',
                                items: [{
                                        fieldLabel: 'Sales Goal',
                                        name: 'salesGoal',
                                        xtype: 'numberfield',                                   
                                        anchor:'95%',
                                        decimalPrecision: '2',

                                }]
                        }]
                }]
                ,buttons: [{text: 'Recalculate'}]
            });
            goalPanel.getForm().load({url:'data.txt', method:'GET'} );          
        });
```

**This is the result:**

[image: extjs]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Where's the typo?

Comment: and it doesn't work in IE if I don't remove the unused comma in "decimalPrecision: 2,"

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS 4.1 seems to now default to accepting a **single data object** instead of a data array, as previously mentioned.

```
{
 success: true,
 data: {
  field1: value1,
  field2: value2
 }
}
```